# Xcode Swift How to add multiple PDF Documents as Attachments in MFMailComposeViewController from String

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableView that displays a bunch of pdf files.
I did the following to get a String of all the selected files:

```
 var values = [String]()
var selected: Bool?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    controller!.loadPDF(file: files![indexPath.row])
    selected = false
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            print("\(files![indexPath.row])")
            values = values.filter{$0 != "\(files![indexPath.row])"}
            selected = true
            print(values)
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    if selected == true{
        print(values)
    }
    else{
        getAllTextFromTableView()
    }
}
func getAllTextFromTableView() {
    guard let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { // if no selected cells just return
        return
    }

    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        values.append(files![indexPath.row])
        print(values)
    }
}
```

The String i am getting will look like this:

["1552389629_zzz.pdf", "1552390079_uu.pdf", "1552391120_uuu.pdf"]

Now i want to add these files as Attachments to an Email.
How can i take every filename, add the DocumentsDirectory path to it and then attach to a newly created Email?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have saved the list of PDFs to the documents directory before hand you can do something like this:

```
func sharePDFs(filePaths: [String]){
    // Initiate MFMailComposeViewController
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    // Obtain documents directory
    let documentsDirec: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    // For each last path component, add on to documents directory and attach to composeVC
    for path in filePaths{
        let fullPath: URL = documentsDirec.appendingPathComponent(path) 
        do{
            let pdfData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: fullPath)

            composeVC.addAttachmentData(pdfData, mimeType: "image/pdf", fileName: "filename.pdf") // Make sure each one is unique so they don't overwrite each other
        }catch{
            print("Error fetching and attaching PDF")
        }

        present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Outside your ViewController
extension ViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! 
I solved it like this:

```
  let savePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("savedPDF/")

    for savePath2 in pdfListController.GlobalVariable.values {

        let file = try? FileHandle(forReadingFrom: savePath.appendingPathComponent("/\(savePath2)"))
        let attachmentData = file?.readDataToEndOfFile()

        composeVC.addAttachmentData(attachmentData!, mimeType: "PDF", fileName: "\(savePath2.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\1234567890_]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil))")
    }
```